# jQuery('<div/>', attributes)

Tags: jquery, properties, attributes

Is there a list of what properties/attributes jQuery supports when creating a new object like this:

```
$('<div/>', {
// these are just examples
    "class": "myClass",
    text: "Hello World",
    click: function(){
        var el = $(this),
            offset = el.offset(),
            info = "L: " + offset.left + ", T: " + offset.top;
        el.text(info);
    }
}).appendTo('body');
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aEQ7M/)

Comment: i don't understand -what you want  with this code ? want to know about any specific property ?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aEQ7M/1/ do you need more info on you object? Console.log and have a look in your browser console

Comment: Code/ fiddle was just an extension to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), as of jQuery 1.8, keys in the object passed to `$()` can be:

- Any attribute name (e.g. `title` or `class`, but not `className`, which is a DOM property, not an attribute),
- Any event type (e.g. `change` or `click`),
- The name of any method exposed by `$.fn` (e.g. `val`, `text`, or even `on`), resulting in that method being applied to the associated value.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Though, how would you define 'on' in this context?

Comment: @PHearst, you would specify a map of events to handlers: `$("<div />", { on: { change: function() {}, click: function() {} } });`. There is a better formatted example in the documentation link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it supports all the normal attributes for the specific element.